# Find the total amount from a given percentage and x amount which on substraction provides the x amount

Tags: arithmetic

I am a freelancer and working with a firm. I provide services, for which I am taking extra 5% as service charge of the firm's amount.

Suppose the firm's amount is 600, and I am chargin 5%.

```
600 + 600%5 = 630
```

This total amount (`630`) again goes to a payment service gateway where they (firm) have already programmed to deduct their share and settle my share (`5%`).

So what happens on payment service gateway is they deduct 5% from the total amount (`i.e., 630`) and not from the firm's actual amount (`i.e., 600`).

```
630 - 630%5 = 598.5
```

As you can see, their share (598.5) reduces by the actual amount (600).

Could you please help me how to produce the total amount to the payment gateway server so that the firm gets their full amount, and I get my 5%.

I guess

```
i.e., total_amount - total_amount %5 = firm_amount
```

Comment: I am not sure to understand what variable you can play with? The firm's amount (which is 600 now) ?

Comment: @MaxFt I thought I could may be change the total amount, so that on substracting total amount with 5% of the total amount, the result will be the firm's actual amount.` i.e., total_amount - total_amount %5 = firm_amount`

Comment: Do you control the payment gateway? I think what you want to do is getting 5% of the amount the firm receive in the end (600). To do this you need to change the percentage taken from your gateway payment service

Comment: If what I say makes sense and seems right I will post a more detailed answer

Comment: @MaxFt Sorry, I don't control the payment gateway.

Comment: @MaxFt I guess, I figured it out.   Total amount = (Firm's amount * 100) / 95.   Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Yes your formula is right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To lay out your comment:

When the payment service gateway deducts $5\%$ of the total payment, they return $95\%$ of the total payment to the firm. So you have $$\text{Firm's net receipt } = \text{Total payment } \times \frac{95}{100}$$ and can find the total payment by dividing both sides by $\frac{95}{100}$ to give $$\text{Total payment } = \text{Firm's net receipt } \div \frac{95}{100}$$ or equivalently $$\text{Total payment } = \text{Firm's net receipt } \times \frac{100}{95}$$ and if you want the firm's net receipt to be $600$ then the total payment should be about $631.58$